# Create bean instance at runtime for interface

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am kind of stuck on a problem with creating beans, or probably i got the wrong intention.. Maybe you can help me solve it:

I got a application which takes in requests for batch processing. For every batch i need to create an own context depending on the parameters issued by the request.

I will try to simplyfy it with the following example:

I receive a request to process in a batch FunctionA which is a implementation for my Function_I interface and has sub-implementation FunctionA_DE and FunctionA_AT

Something like this:

```
public interface Function_I {
   String doFunctionStuff()
}

public abstract class FunctionA implements Function_I {

   FunctionConfig funcConfig;

   public FunctionA(FunctionConfig funcConfig) {
      this.funcConfig = funcConfig;
   }

   public String doFunctionStuff() {
      // some code
      String result = callSpecificFunctionStuff();
      // more code
      return result;
   }

   protected abstract String callSpecificFunctionStuff();
}

public class FunctionA_DE extends FunctionA {
   public FunctionA_DE(FunctionConfig funcConf) {
      super(funcConf)
   }
   
   protected String callSpecifiFunctionStuff() {
      //do some specificStuff
      return result;
   }
}

public class FunctionA_AT extends FunctionA {
   public FunctionA_AT(FunctionConfig funcConf) {
      super(funcConf)
   }

   protected String callSpecifiFunctionStuff() {
      //do some specificStuff
      return result;
   }
}
```

what would be the Spring-Boot-Way of creating a instance for FunctionA_DE to get it as Function_I for the calling part of the application, and what should it look like when i add FunctionB with FunctionB_DE / FunctionB_AT to my classes..

I thought it could be something like:

```
PSEUDO CODE
@Configuration
public class FunctionFactory {
   @Bean(SCOPE=SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) // i need a new instance everytime i call it
   public Function_I createFunctionA(FunctionConfiguration funcConfig) {
      // create Function depending on the funcConfig so either FunctionA_DE or FunctionA_AT
   }
}
```

and i would call it by Autowiring the FunctionFactory into my calling class and use it with

```
someSpringFactory.createFunction(functionConfiguration);
```

but i cant figure it out to create a Prototype-Bean for the function with passing a parameter.. And i cant really find a solution to my question by browsing through SO, but maybe i just got the wrong search terms.. Or my approach to solve this issue i totally wrong (maybe stupid), nobody would solve it the spring-boot-way but stick to Factories.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone and thanks for reading my question.

after a discussion with a friend who is well versed in the spring framework i came to the conclusion that my approach or my favoured solution was not what i was searching for and is not how spring should be used. Because the Function_I-Instance depends on the for the specific batch loaded configuration it is not recommended to manage all these instances as @Beans.

In the end i decided to not manage the instances for my Function_I with spring. but instead i build a Controller / Factory which is a @Controller-Class and let this class build the instance i need with the passed parameters for decision making on runtime.

This is how it looks (Pseudo-Code)

```
@Controller
public class FunctionController {

   SomeSpringManagedClass ssmc;

   public FunctionController(@Autowired SomeSpringManagedClass ssmc) {
      this.ssmc = ssmc;
   }

   public Function_I createFunction(FunctionConfiguration funcConf) {
      boolean funcA, cntryDE;
      // code to decide the function
      if(funcA && cntryDE) {
         return new FunctionA_DE(funcConf);
      } else if(funB && cntryDE) {
         return new FunctionB_DE(funcConf);
      } // maybe more else if...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Springs's application context. Create a bean for each of the interfaces but annotate it with a specific profile e.g. "Function-A-AT". Now when you have to invoke it, you can simply set the application context of spring accordingly and the right bean should be used by Spring.

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for your quick response. The spring context may contain some informations for the creation of the Function implementation, but it won't solve the problem of passing the specific FunctionConfiguration as a parameter.

Comment: Hi Marc, is it not possible that you pass it on in the function configuration and then in the constructor access the spring application context and modify the active profile?
(In the answer I forgot to mention the profile, will update it.)

Comment: Hi Simon, i am not sure how i would implement your suggestion, maybe you can help me with some code?

I am not sure if you got my current situation, because of the simplification of my question.

I got my Application which can be requested to execute a batch for different functions (you can call multiple functions in one batch aswell)

So when i receive the request i need to create 1-n instances for FunctionA, FunctionB etc.and every instance needs its own recources). The instance will be created with the FunctionConfiguration which is received from our storage..

Comment: Thank you Simon for trying to help me. As you can see in my answer i came up with a solutation with the help of a friend.